# Query for Min, Max, Avg, and Last Value in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I am trying to find Max, min, avg and last value of a column in single query.
Platform: SQL Server 2012

Sample Table:

```
SN  Month  Acc  Bal
------------------------
1     7    101   1,000/-
2     7    101   1,500/-
3     7    101   1,700/-
4     8    101   1,200/-
5     8    101   900/-
6     9    101   2,500/-
```

Query I wrote:

```
select 
    [Month], [Acc],
    min(Bal) as MinBal,
    avg(Bal) as AvgBal,
    max(Bal) as MaxBal
    --, ??? for as LastBal
from 
    MyTable
Group By 
    [Month], [Acc]
```

Query with `Last_Value` returns all records instead of aggregated records

```
select 
    [Month], [Acc],
    min(Bal) as MinBal,
    avg(Bal) as AvgBal,
    max(Bal) as MaxBal,
    LAST_VALUE(Bal) OVER (partition by [Acc] order by [Month]) as LastBal
from 
    MyTable
Group By 
    [Month], [Acc], Bal
```

Also including `last_value(bal)` is generating an error with bal required on group by list

> Column 'Bal' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: [`LAST_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql), perhaps?

Comment: Define your definition of last.

Comment: last_value is giving me all records instead of aggregated few records

Comment: try `LAST_VALUE(Bal) OVER (partition by [Acc], [Month] order by  SN)`

Comment: adding last_value asks me to add bal column in group by list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this solution-

**DATA Generation**

```
CREATE TABLE Alls
(
     SN INT
    ,[Month] INT
    ,Acc INT
    ,Bal INT
)
GO

INSERT INTO Alls VALUES
(1,  7,    101,   1000),
(2,  7,    101,   1500),
(3,  7,    101,   1700),
(4,  8,    101,   1200),
(5,  8,    101,   900),
(6,  9,    101,   2500)
GO
```

**SOLUTION**

```
SELECT sn,Acc,[Month] ,Bal
, MIN(Bal) OVER(PARTITION BY Acc,[Month]) MinBal
, AVG(Bal*1.) OVER(PARTITION BY Acc,[Month]) AvgBal
, MAX(Bal) OVER(PARTITION BY Acc,[Month]) MaxBal
, FIRST_VALUE(Bal) OVER(PARTITION BY Acc,[Month] ORDER BY SN DESC) lastVal
FROM Alls
ORDER By SN
```

**OUTPUT**

```
sn          Acc         Month       Bal         MinBal      AvgBal           MaxBal      lastVal
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------------- ----------- -----------
1           101         7           1000        1000        1400.000000      1700        1700
2           101         7           1500        1000        1400.000000      1700        1700
3           101         7           1700        1000        1400.000000      1700        1700
4           101         8           1200        900         1050.000000      1200        900
5           101         8           900         900         1050.000000      1200        900
6           101         9           2500        2500        2500.000000      2500        2500

(6 rows affected)
```

**IF you only need acc,month and other aggregate columns then use below-**

**SOLUTION**

```
SELECT Acc,[Month],MAX(MinBal)MinBal,MAX(AvgBal)AvgBal,MAX(MaxBal)MaxBal,MAX(lastVal)lastVal
FROM
(
    SELECT sn,Acc,[Month] ,Bal
    , MIN(Bal) OVER(PARTITION BY Acc,[Month]) MinBal
    , AVG(Bal*1.) OVER(PARTITION BY Acc,[Month]) AvgBal
    , MAX(Bal) OVER(PARTITION BY Acc,[Month]) MaxBal
    , FIRST_VALUE(Bal) OVER(PARTITION BY Acc,[Month] ORDER BY SN DESC) lastVal
    FROM Alls
)u GROUP BY Acc,[Month]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Acc         Month       MinBal      AvgBal           MaxBal      lastVal
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------------- ----------- -----------
101         7           1000        1400.000000      1700        1700
101         8           900         1050.000000      1200        900
101         9           2500        2500.000000      2500        2500

(3 rows affected)
```

Comment: your solution works perfectly... btw why that avg(Bal*1.) for avg and what can be the performanace issue

Comment: To make the Bal numeric just in case if we have decimal values in bal column otherwise avg will not be correct.  please see this example - SELECT a, AVG(a*1.) OVER() decimalValuesavg ,  AVG(a) OVER() normalavgvalues  FROM 
(SELECT 1 a UNION ALL SELECT 2)b

Answer (score 2):

```
select * 
from 
( SELECT sn, Acc, [Month], Bal
       , MIN(Bal) OVER(PARTITION BY Acc, [Month]) MinBal
       , AVG(Bal) OVER(PARTITION BY Acc, [Month]) AvgBal
       , MAX(Bal) OVER(PARTITION BY Acc, [Month]) MaxBal
       , row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY Acc, [Month] ORDER BY SN DESC) as rn 
) tt
where rn = 1
ORDER By sn
```

Comment: your query looks sweet one... (y)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve as below:

```
select 
 tt.Month
, tt.Acc
, min(Bal) as MinBal
, avg(Bal) as AvgBal 
, max(Bal) as MaxBal
, latest.balance
FROM #tbl1 as tt 
JOIN (
  SELECT 
  id
  ,month
  ,acc
  ,bal as balance
FROM #tbl1 AS t1
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id)
                 FROM #tbl1 AS t2 
                 WHERE t1.month = t2.month 
                   AND t1.acc = t2.acc 
                 GROUP BY month, acc)
) as latest
on tt.month = latest.month 
                   AND tt.acc = latest.acc 
Group By tt.Month, tt.Acc, latest.balance


DROP TABLE #tbl1
```